# Determine if a Vector is pointing in the positive or negative half-plane

Tags: vectors

Determine if the vector $(1,2)$ is pointing in the positive or negative half-plane of $2x-y-3=0$

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.  I found a point on the line $(2,1)$.  Next I found the end of the vector by $(2+1,1+2)=(3,3)$   I then plugged this new point into the equation and got $0$.  I am not sure, but if you get a positive number the vector is pointing positive, etc.  Does a value of zero mean neither positive or negative?

Comment: The direction of the line is also $(1, 2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $y=2x+3 \implies (t, 2t+3)$, so the line has direction $(1,2)$.

The vector is parallel to the line and points in neither of the half planes.

Answer (score 0):

That is right.  $(3,3)$ is also on the line so you are not pointing into either half-plane.